# Error producing XML from JAXB (WebService)

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, marshalling

I have following code which is returning `Foo`

```
@GET
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Foo getXML (){
    System.out.println ("getXML Request");
    Foo f = new Foo();
    d.setA("test");
    d.setB("xyxyx");
    return f;
}
```

and my `Foo` Class is

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo{

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

        public String getB (){
           return b;
        }

        public String getA (){
           return a;
        }

    @XmlAttribute(name="atrribB")
    private String b;

    @XmlElement(name="elementA")
    private String a;

}
```

While doing so, I got error on `Foo` that `Class has two properties of the same name "A"` and same goes for `B`.

When i deleted `getters` method for both of these properties, everything was fine. am i suppose not to create getter setters and leave fields has public ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either annotate the get methods

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo{

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="atrribB")
    public String getB (){
       return b;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="elementA")
    public String getA (){
       return a;
    }

    private String b;

    private String a;

}
```

or specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo{

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getB (){
       return b;
    }

    public String getA (){
       return a;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="atrribB")
    private String b;

    @XmlElement(name="elementA")
    private String a;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: does it go on both get/set fields? since i will be using this class to generate/receive XML at some point.

Comment: Just on one of the get or set methods.  I have updated my answer to demonstrate this.